# Python shallow copy doesn't automatically change the variable when the other variable is changed

Tags: python-3.x, shallow-copy

I have a piece of code that is supposed to use shallow copy to make automatically changing variables: pos_x and pos_y, when pos is changed.

```
import copy
class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [1, 2]
        self.pos_x = copy.copy(self.pos[0])
        self.pos_y = copy.copy(self.pos[1])


temp = AClass()
temp.pos[0] = 5
print(temp.pos_x)
```

Why does that output 1 instead of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because what your code is doing is not what you think it is doing. The shallow copy of a list will make a new list and add references to the objects inside it.

The thing is that the reference of the two elements (Which are numbers) you have there are references to an immutable object 1 and 2, and not to the specific 1 and 2 inside your list. You can check that by using id:

```
temp = AClass()
id(temp.pos[0])
id(1)
```

The IDs are the same, which means that your temp.pos[0] is pointing to the "global" 1.

If you really wanted to do something like what you thought without big changes (like using methods to change pos), it would have to be something like this:

```
import copy
class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [[[1]], [[2]]]
        self.pos_x = copy.copy(self.pos[0])
        self.pos_y = copy.copy(self.pos[1])
```

Then, copy would create a new list, and insert the reference to the list with the 1 there. And changing t[0][0][0] would also change x[0][0]. But that's probably far from being a good way to do it. And again you can verify that the ids of t[0][0] and x[0] are the same, so they are both pointing to the same list.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events was:

1. Created `temp`, which involved assigning copies of elements of `temp.pos` to `temp.pos_x` and `temp.pos_y`.
2. Replace the value of `temp.pos`.
3. Print the value of `temp.pos_x`.

There is *nothing* in those code that causes `pos_x` or `pos_y` to change when `pos` changes.

Comment: Isn't temp.pos_x pointing to temp.pos[0]? So when temp.pos[0] is changed, isn't it supposed to change temp.pos_x?

Comment: Yes, `temp.pos_x` is pointing to the *original* `temp.pos[0]`.  That doesn't change when you set `temp.pos` to be a new list.